# Why select returns only the first value?

Tags: javascript, select, onchange

There are two values in function. Input and select, everything works normally except that the select returns the first value (px). Where did I get it wrong?

```
<input id="width" onchange="Width()" type="number" placeholder="0" min="" max="" step="0.1">

<select id="widthpixselpercentage" onchange="Width()" >
<option value="px">px</option>
<option value="%">%</option>
</select>

<div id="someDiv"></div>
```

```
function Width(){
var x = document.getElementById("width").value;
var y = document.getElementById("widthpixselpercentage").value;
        document.getElementById(someDiv).style.width = x + y;

}
```

Comment: option is an option of the select box, select has no 'value' it has a selectedIndex which you can use to find out which option the user has selected

Comment: Close your input tag at the end /> also, you mean it is not being listed or the JS cannot catch it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript)

Comment: @Jay That was the situation for twenty years ago, nowadays `select` element has a value, which reflects the value of the selected option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want value from select box by using javascript:

```
var select_box = document.getElementById("widthpixselpercentage");
var y = select_box.options[select_box.selectedIndex].value;
```

If you want text from select box by using javascript:

```
var select_box = document.getElementById("widthpixselpercentage");
var y = select_box.options[select_box.selectedIndex].text;
```

Please try the following:

```js
function Width(){
var x = document.getElementById("width").value;
var select_box = document.getElementById("widthpixselpercentage");
var y = select_box.options[select_box.selectedIndex].value;
        document.getElementById("someDiv").style.width = x + y;

}
```

```css
#someDiv{
border:1px solid;
height:5px;
}
```

```html
<input id="width" onchange="Width()" type="number" placeholder="0" min="" max="" step="0.1">

<select id="widthpixselpercentage" onchange="Width()" >
<option value="px">px</option>
<option value="%">%</option>
</select>

<div id="someDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to the following sample code:

```js
function Width(vv)
{
 alert(vv.value);
}
```

```html
<input id="width" onchange="Width(this)" type="number" placeholder="0" min="" max="" step="0.1">

<select id="widthpixselpercentage" onchange="Width(this)" >
<option value="px">px</option>
<option value="%">%</option>
</select>

<div id="someDiv"></div>
```